# Certificates on WSL

Tags: debian, proxy, certificates

I am working with Debian, installed on Windows through WSL and I am having some annoying problems with certificates. I am behind a corporate network and not entirely sure how is setup (proxy, self signed cert...)

There are quite a lot of actions that are failing to validate a certificate, even a simple `sudo apt update` is returning the following for some repositories: `CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none`.

Similar results with cURL, wget etc...

Since everything works perfectly on Windows, I tried to import the certificates from it.

Running `openssl s_client -connect someDomainHere.com:443 </dev/null` would give me the root certificate name, then moving it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and finally `sudo update-ca-certificates` does not change anything...

I would be very grateful is someone has an idea since I have no moer tricks left :)

Thanks

EDIT: forgot to mentioned I also tried to update and reinstall the ca-certificates

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, which commands you tried **exactly** (as the case may be, my hints are less helpfull).

**1.** this commands works for me (without DPI-Firwall)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode#update-your-linux-distribution

**2.**
If your firewall proxy is using HTTPS Inspection [(DPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection#Encryption_and_tunneling_subverting_DPI)
then make sure, **it's** "Certificate Trust chain" is installed

Please attend carefully (Certificates must have a .crt extension)
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ca-certificates/update-ca-certificates.8.en.html

There are different ways to get the chain, for example via web-browser.

(or not tested:

```
openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text
```

example.com stands for any server behind the firewall)

**3.** If you use wsl2: check if you are affected by a wsl2-bug with automatic generation of /etc/resolv.conf (wrong nameserver address)

To identify the correct IP-Address you can use this powershell cmdlet:

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily ipv4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
```